# where is the so_survey csv or how can i find it?

Tags: dataset

```
# Import pandas
import pandas as pd
 
# Import so_survey_csv into so_survey_df
so_survey_df = pd.read_csv(so_survey_csv)
 
# Print the first five rows of the DataFrame
print(so_survey_df.head())
 
# Print the data type of each column
print(so_survey_df.dtypes)
```

where is the so_survey_csv or how can i find it?

Comment: I'm afraid we can't know where your files or data is or how to get it... You can't ask us "where did I put my phone?" or something like that either - only you can know that.

Comment: Hm it seems this is from some online coding tutorial. It says there that this variable will contain a URL to a CSV file. In that case, it will probably be set by the code that calls your code. Just trust that it's a URL.